# Random URL website address from core data that holds a picture to display in UIImage in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage

I'm new to using xcode, so any information or links would be helpful. If I had a RANDOM website url in coredata, how would I be able to direct my UIImage to get the photo from that website to display in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `imageURL` is a `NSString *` ivar or property where you hold your URL.
To get the image this should work:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

Of course you should add some error checking but this should get you into the right direction.